# No Response at Page after Refresh in Silverlight 5 Prism 4.1 Unity, MVVM application C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, telerik, prism

I'm seeing a strange issue in my Application which is in Silverlight 5, Prism 4.1 Unity & MVVM + Telerik Control.

So far I have only 1 Module in my application. When I Run the application from VS2013 and Browser loads the screen fine. After this when I refresh the Screen No Buttons Noting works on screen. It become static show.

More when I minimize the Browser & After sometime I open the browser again, I see nothing in my screen except grey color.

This is Happening in IE for Now. Firefox & Crome I haven't seen issue like this.

**My MVVM pattern is like this**

Abs.Infrstructure project :

```
interface View.IView{ IViewModel ViewModel{set;get;}}
interface ViewModel.IViewModel {IView View{set;get;}}

class ViewModel.ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged{ 
   public ViewModelBase(IView view){ 
    View=view
  } 
 ...
}
```

Now my Module :

```
interface View.IUserTabView :IView{}

 //class of UserTab.xaml
 class View.UseTab : UserControl, IView{
   // Setting DataContext as IUserTabViewModel
 }

interface ViewModel.IUserTabViewModel : IViewModel{ ...} 
class ViewModel.UserTabViewModel : ViewModelBase, IUserTabViewModel{ 
  ...
  // Command , Etc
}
```

My Module :IModule

```
public class AdminModule : IModule
{
    private IRegionManager regionManager;
    IUnityContainer container;
    public AdminModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.RegisterViewsAndServices();
        if (this.regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName(RegionNames.FOOTER_REGION))
        {
            var vm1 = this.container.Resolve<IAdministratorTabContainerViewModel>();
            this.regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.HPMS_CENTER_REGION].Add(vm1.View);

            // Tab Navigation Set Up
            this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.HPMS_ADMINTAB_REGION, typeof(IUsersTabViewModel));
        }
    }
  protected void RegisterViewsAndServices() {
        //Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView
        //this.container.RegisterType<RadGridView>();
        this.container.RegisterType<IUsersTabView, UsersTab>();
        this.container.RegisterType<IUsersTabViewModel, UsersTabViewModel>();
  }
}
```

All DelegateCommand, AggrigateCommands etc I'm initializing in ViewModels Class Constructor, So when I run first time they run  " bool CanAdd " too. ( Is this default behaviour? )

- Is there any Memory Leak?
- How I can correct this issue?
  -Any Wrong Implementation / Approach of prism, MVVM ,OpenRIA etc?

I wrote this code for reference if deregister etc or any life cycle issue is there for better understanding. App module contains 1 RadTabControl, 1 Tab which have RadGRidView and thats all. of course I've OpenRIA Domain Service for data (EF6 & DevArt Oracle Connector).

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'refresh' do you mean an F5 key refresh? 
If so, yes, this is a problem with later versions of Internet Explorer ...
[Silverlight app disappears on page refresh in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492045/silverlight-app-disappears-on-page-refresh-in-ie10)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/db07a063-35e2-4385-bf91-fe9324ee3d31/silverlight-app-disappears-on-page-refresh-in-ie10

The workarounds seem to be either forcing compatibility mode (down to IE7 or 8) or loading the Silverlight object dynamically with Javascript.