# Silverlight app turns into white page on refreshing of IE11

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, silverlight

I am struggling with an IE/Silverlight bug which seems to be known since quite a while: When a silverlight page is refreshed in IE10, the app turns into a white page. No error messages or anything alike. I am using IE11 and the behavior is the same. It is absolutely ridiculous  that such a showstopper still hasn't been fixed and I was not able to find one helpful response from Microsoft. Anyway, I found workarounds in this thread:

[SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492045/silverlight-app-disappears-on-page-refresh-in-ie10)

but I don't manage to get any of the workarounds to work properly.

This is my latest try:

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Manager</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #silverlightControlHost {
        height: 100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
            var appSource = "";
            if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
                appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
            }

            var errorType = args.ErrorType;
            var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

            if (errorType == "ImageError" || errorType == "MediaError") {
                return;
            }

            var errMsg = "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " +  appSource + "\n" ;

            errMsg += "Code: "+ iErrorCode + "    \n";
            errMsg += "Category: " + errorType + "       \n";
            errMsg += "Message: " + args.ErrorMessage + "     \n";

            if (errorType == "ParserError") {
                errMsg += "File: " + args.xamlFile + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
            }
            else if (errorType == "RuntimeError") {           
                if (args.lineNumber != 0) {
                    errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                    errMsg += "Position: " +  args.charPosition + "     \n";
                }
                errMsg += "MethodName: " + args.methodName + "     \n";
            }

            throw new Error(errMsg);
        }
    </script>

     <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" />

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
        <a id="myLink" ></a>
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/Manager.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            var shc = document.getElementById("silverlightControlHost");
            document.getElementById("myLink").focus();
        </script>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I included the meta-tag for compatibility mode and the java snippet to focus another control. Neither seems to work.

1. Are there any updates on this issue which I have missed?
2. Are there any mistakes in the code shown above?
3. Could someone post a complete page which implements a working workaround?

Additional information:
OS: Windows 8.1
IE: 11.0.96000
SL: 5.1.30514.0

Comment: SL in its current state is a mess. Do you have a link to your current site exhibiting the error by chance?

Comment: Hi Brandon, unfortunately the site requires login, so you could only see the entry page. Refreshing the entry page works, I guess because it just performs another GET request. Must be some different mechanism compared to refreshing the running silverlight app. Actually, I find this whole thing quite surprising. There must be thousands of LOB applications relying on silverlight. Can you explain what else is wrong with silverlight? I have started a mission critical project in silverlight and this kind of issues makes me wonder whether to switch platforms as long as I can.

Comment: ...so, I know that it is quite off-topic, but maybe you could just give me your personal opinion whether to keep on developing in silverlight or to switch to something else (what?).

Comment: This is still not fixed (well, not surprising really because SL isn't actively supported with fixes any more), and like you I have not been able to successfully implement any of the work-arounds given. Our users are encouraged to click in the address bar and press enter if they want to 'refresh', rather than trying to use the refresh button or F5.

Comment: I'm on my phone but it may be possible to prevent the F5 browser refresh in the first place w/ JS. As for SL, it's dying quickly - MS is not committed to it long-term and HTML5 has won the battle all around. I would run as fast as you can toward the ASP.NET MVC / HTML5 stack if at all possible, you'll have to at some point when SL support is officially discontinued.